# Is there a way to map a property to a custom type in Dapper?

Tags: c#, dapper

We are looking at Dapper to simplify our mapping logic.  It looks pretty promising except for one thing.  We use custom types for our ids.  For example:

```
public class MyEntityIdentity 
{
    public int IdentityValue { get; }
    public MyEntityIdentity(int identity) { IdentityValue = identity; }
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public MyEntityIdentity Identity { get; set; }
    int Prop1 { get; set; }
    string Prop2 { get; set; }
    bool Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

With the SQL table looking something like:

```
create table [dbo].[MyEntity] (
    my_entity_id int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    prop1 int NULL,
    prop2 varchar(100) NULL,
    prop3 bit NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT PK_MyEntity PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (my_entity_id ASC)
)
```

How can we map the "Identity" property?

Comment: Your my_entity_id is still an int, so you should map it as an int directly

Comment: What purpose does having that entity serve?  Your ID is an `int`.  IMO, you are overcomplicating your model for little gain.

Comment: Amy, we have an Interface for identities that make them work with a complex legacy Repository model.  The legacy identities can be pretty complex themselves.  I am creating simple entities and identities for new development, but they still have to be able to work within the legacy system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use custom type handler like this:

```
public class IdentityHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<MyEntityIdentity>
{
    public override MyEntityIdentity Parse(object value)
    {
        return new MyEntityIdentity((int)value);
    }

    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, MyEntityIdentity value)
    {
        parameter.Value = value.IdentityValue;
    }
}
```

And register it like this:

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new IdentityHandler());
```